# Hard links on AFP

Tags: macports, hardlink, afp

I'm trying to run MacPorts via AFP. Most ports run fine but I'm trying to install mercurial, which requires the MacPorts Python 2.6 file.

Building Python 2.6 chokes on the following line in the makefile:

```
ln python2.6 python
```

which produces the following error:

```
ln: python: Operation not supported
```

Essentially hard links on AFP don't work. Can I replace that line with a symbolic link? Is there a way to get hard links to work on AFP, or to run the system version of Python with a specific port? I don't have root on the box so solutions that require root probably won't work in this case.

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to replace that line with a symbolic link (`ln -s`). It only sets the "default" version of Python to be run when calling the `python` executable.